# RTMP server - without watermarks everything works fine --- with watermark one stream will not work nginx ffmpeg overlay watermark

Tags: nginx, ffmpeg, rtmp, watermark

okay so i used the below config and everything works great both youtube and facebook work .

```
rtmp {
    server {
        listen 1935;
        chunk_size 8192;
        application live {
        record off;
        live on;
        push rtmp://a.rtmp.youtube.com/live2/djfghjkdfhgkjsdfglsjdfhj;
                push rtmp://127.0.0.1:19350/rtmp/453uy4uty8ryt85ty85yt8; (facbook)
                    }
    
        }
    

    }
```

Now i have tried 2 seprate way to add a water mark (Youtube works fine Every time)
Facebook does not stream at all let alone with a watermark

examples i have tried below

```
rtmp {
server {
    listen 1935;
    chunk_size 8192;
    application live {
    record off;
    live on;
            exec /bin/ffmpeg  -i rtmp://127.0.0.1:1935/live/$name
             -vf "movie=/etc/nginx/images/logo.png[logo];[0][logo]overlay=0:300"
             -c:v libx264 -f flv rtmp://127.0.0.1:1935/push/$name;
              }

    application push {
    live on;
    push rtmp://a.rtmp.youtube.com/live2/djfghjkdfhgkjsdfglsjdfhj;
            }
   }
}
```

and another

```
rtmp {
server {
    listen 1935;
    chunk_size 8192;
    application live {
    record off;
    live on;
            exec /bin/ffmpeg  -i rtmp://127.0.0.1:1935/live/$name
             -vf "movie=/etc/nginx/images/logo.png[logo];[0][logo]overlay=0:300"
             -c:v libx264 -f flv rtmp://127.0.0.1:1935/push/$name;
    
                    exec /bin/ffmpeg  -i rtmp://127.0.0.1:1935/live/$name
             -vf "movie=/etc/nginx/images/logo.png[logo];[0][logo]overlay=0:300"
             -c:v libx264 -f flv rtmp://127.0.0.1:1935/pushh/$name;
            }

    application push {
    live on;
    push rtmp://a.rtmp.youtube.com/live2/djfghjkdfhgkjsdfglsjdfhj;
            }

            application pushh {
            live on;
            push rtmp://127.0.0.1:19350/rtmp/453uy4uty8ryt85ty85yt8;
            }
   }
}
```

Now for the life of me i just cannot get my brain to work.
i am very new to rtmp and have tried a dozen other ways before coming here for help.

i know this is going to be something i where i am making such a simple mistake

but on the other hand paying over $49 for restream.io for a shoddy service i just have to learn this for my own servers

Answer (score 0):

exec /bin/ffmpeg -i rtmp://localhost/aaaaaaa -i /etc/nginx/images/logo.png -filter_complex "overlay=10:10,split=2[out1][out2]" -map '[out1]' -map 0:a -s 640x480 -c:v libx264 -c:a aac -ac 1 -strict -2 -b:v 256k -b:a 32k -tune zerolatency -preset veryfast -crf 23 -f flv rtmp://localhost/push-map '[out2]' -map 0:a -s 1280x720 -c:v libx264 -c:a aac -ac 1 -strict -2 -b:v 768k -b:a 96k -tune zerolatency -preset veryfast -crf 23 -f flv rtmp://localhost/pushh;

working answer :)